# What happens when I use `ic_cdk::spawn` in an IC canister and then panic after?

Tags: rust, internet-computer

If I have something like this, and I call `test`, will the async call to `test_2` be made?

```
#[update]
async fn test() {
    println!("test was called");
    ic_cdk::spawn(async move {
        let _: () = ic_cdk::call(ic_cdk::api::id(), "test_2", ()).await.unwrap();
    });
    panic!("Panic at the disco!");
}

#[update]
async fn test_2() {
    println!("Playground canister test_2 was called");
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if information like this were included in the `spawn` rustdoc.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run this with a `StateMachine` test:

```
use dfn_candid::candid_one;
use ic_base_types::PrincipalId;
use ic_nns_test_utils::state_test_helpers::{create_canister, update_with_sender};
use ic_state_machine_tests::StateMachine;
use std::time::Duration;

#[test]
fn test_canister_playground() {
    let state_machine = StateMachine::new();

    let canister_playground_wasm =
        Project::cargo_bin_maybe_from_env("canister-playground-canister", &[]);

    let playground_id =
        create_canister(&state_machine, canister_playground_wasm, Some(vec![]), None);

    let response: () = update_with_sender(
        &state_machine,
        playground_id,
        "test",
        candid_one,
        (),
        PrincipalId::new_anonymous(),
    )
    .unwrap();

    // Up to 10 seconds of excitement
    for _ in 1..100 {
        state_machine.tick();
        state_machine.advance_time(Duration::from_millis(100))
    }

    println!("Response: {:?}", response);
}
```

I got the following output:

```
2021-05-06 19:17:10 UTC: [Canister rwlgt-iiaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-cai] Playground Canister Init!
2021-05-06 19:17:12 UTC: [Canister rwlgt-iiaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-cai] Playground test was called
2021-05-06 19:17:12 UTC: [Canister rwlgt-iiaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-cai] Playground test - spawns were called
2021-05-06 19:17:12 UTC: [Canister rwlgt-iiaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-cai] Panicked at 'Panic at the disco!', rs/nns/integration_tests/test_canisters/canister_playground_canister.rs:38:5
```

It appears that panicking prevents the `spawn` call from finishing execution, as the state is rolled back after panic (and part of the state was that the call was going to run later).